# Add token authentication for webApi controller to existing asp.net MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I currently have a Web API controller added to an existing MVC 5 project (not using .net core) and I was able to successfully create and get data from the controller that I have set up. The purpose of the API is to pass data between it and a mobile application that uses the same data source that the MVC project uses (I will also be calling existing methods in the project from the API so I would prefer the API exist in the MVC project). I am now looking for a way to add token authentication to the API, as I only want logged in users in the mobile application to be allowed to access the API. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution should be to use the [Token Validation Middleware](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/consuming/overview.html) from the IdentityServer 3 suite.
Just add the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/) and configure your application following the doc:

```
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    // turn off any default mapping on the JWT handler
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44333/core",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1" }
        });

    app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());
  }
}
```

It's ok to set 
`app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication()` only
 prior to 
`app.UseCookieAuthentication()` and `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()`
 and call 
`GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)` in Global.asax
Such approach allows to combine token and cookie-based auth in one MVC application.
The only problem for today is that IdentityServer 3 family tools are frozen and support System.IdentityModel 4 and OWIN 3 only, so

**update:**
The preferred solution for ASP.NET 4.6+ becomes [IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation/) -- a fork, refactored according to the recent framework changes.

Comment: Since it is an MVC 5 project, there is no Startup file. Where would I add this code?

Comment: You have to reference owin. But it will be added automatically as a dependency for  Identity package. and then you'll be able to mark any custom class with 
'[OwinStartupAttribute]'. Guess, it's a totally separate question, but I've described the basics...

Comment: @d_f I'm facing the same issue. `app` doesn't have a `UseWebApi` method. I want keep cookie auth to controllers but apply JWT auth for api controllers and be able to use the `Authorize` attribute on them.

Comment: @emzero it's ok to set `app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication()` only (prior to `app.UseCookieAuthentication()` and `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()`) and call `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)` in Global.asax